# Not able to refer resource id created by using for each in terraform into other resource

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a Azure Load balancer module with all its other properties such as backendaddress pool etc. below is my code

[resource azure load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Pks.png)
[resource azure backendaddrespool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oetto.png)

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "lb-test" {
 for_each           = { for lb in var.load_balancers : lb.name => lb }
 name                = each.value.name
 resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
 location            = each.value.location
 sku = each.value.sku
 edge_zone = each.value.edge_zone
 sku_tier = each.value.sku_tier
 frontend_ip_configuration {
   name = each.value.name
   private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.private_ip_address_allocation
   private_ip_address_version = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.private_ip_address_version
   public_ip_address_id = var.public_ip_address_id
   subnet_id = var.subnet_id
   zones = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.zones
 }
 
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "bckaddresspool" {
 for_each         = { for bckaddresspool in var.backend_address_pool : bckaddresspool.name => bckaddresspool }
  name            = each.value.name
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb-test[each.key].id
  virtual_network_id = var.virtual_network_id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_lb.lb-test ]
}
```

Now when i am taking the id of the LB created in the other 2 resource which is backendaddresspool and loadbalancer probe it is giving me following error

in resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "azlb_probe":
loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.lb-test[each.key].id

azurerm_lb.lb-test is object with 1 attribute "LB1"
each.key is "Probe1"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

can anybody help with this error as i tried every possible way to take the id as an input but still its giving me issues.

in resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "azlb_probe":
│   45:   loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.lb-test[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_lb.lb-test is object with 1 attribute "LB1"
│     │ each.key is "Probe1"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Also i am passing all my values through tfvars file.

Comment: Please share the code you tried @SarahPotrick

Comment: attached the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to refer resource id created by using for_each in terraform into other resource and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error message you're seeing indicates that there's a mismatch between the keys you're using in your `for_each` loops and the keys present in the actual data structures you've defined. The error is specifically pointing out that the key `"Probe1"` does not exist in the `azurerm_lb.lb-test` collection.

The major Issues that causes the errors are:

- The `for_each` loop in `azurerm_lb_probe` seems to be using keys that don't match the keys in `azurerm_lb.lb-test`. The keys used in `for_each` must exactly match those in the resource you're referencing.
- The reference `azurerm_lb.lb-test[each.key].id` may be incorrect if the keys between the load balancer and the probes are not intended to be aligned.

To overcome this I tried a terraform configuration which matches with the requirement.

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  address_space       = var.vnet_address_space
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
  name                = "vksb-publicip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  for_each            = var.load_balancers
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = each.value.sku
  
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.name
    private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.private_ip_address_allocation // Can be "Static" or "Dynamic"
    private_ip_address            = each.value.frontend_ip_configuration.private_ip_address
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "bckaddresspool" {
  for_each         = var.backend_address_pools
  name             = each.value.name
  loadbalancer_id  = azurerm_lb.lb[each.value.load_balancer_name].id
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {
  for_each         = var.probes
  name             = each.value.name
  loadbalancer_id  = azurerm_lb.lb[each.value.load_balancer_name].id
  protocol         = each.value.protocol
  port             = each.value.port
  request_path     = each.value.request_path
  interval_in_seconds = each.value.interval_in_seconds
  number_of_probes = each.value.number_of_probes
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region to deploy the resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual network"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space for the virtual network"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "subnet_name" {
  description = "The name of the subnet"
  type        = string
}

variable "subnet_address_prefixes" {
  description = "The address prefixes for the subnet"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "load_balancers" {
  description = "A map of load balancer configurations"
  type        = map(object({
    name                        = string
    sku                         = string
    frontend_ip_configuration = object({
      name                                  = string
      private_ip_address_allocation         = string
      private_ip_address                  = string
    })
  }))
}

variable "backend_address_pools" {
  description = "A map of backend address pool configurations"
  type        = map(object({
    name                = string
    load_balancer_name  = string
  }))
}

variable "probes" {
  description = "A map of load balancer probe configurations"
  type        = map(object({
    name                  = string
    load_balancer_name    = string
    protocol              = string
    port                  = number
    request_path          = string
    interval_in_seconds   = number
    number_of_probes      = number
  }))
}
```

**terrafrom.tfvars:**

```
resource_group_name = "vksb-resources"
location            = "West Europe"
vnet_name           = "vksb-vnet"
vnet_address_space  = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
subnet_name         = "vksb-subnet"
subnet_address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

load_balancers = {
  "lb1" = {
    name = "vksb-lb1"
    sku  = "Standard"
    frontend_ip_configuration = {
      name                          = "vksb-fe-config"
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
      private_ip_address            = "10.0.1.4"
    }
  }
}

backend_address_pools = {
  "pool1" = {
    name               = "vksb-bap1"
    load_balancer_name = "lb1"
  }
}

probes = {
  "probe1" = {
    name                  = "vksb-probe1"
    load_balancer_name    = "lb1"
    protocol              = "Http"
    port                  = 80
    request_path          = "/"
    interval_in_seconds   = 15
    number_of_probes      = 2
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thankyou so much it worked for me